# Want to give values in sql command dynamically by the dropdown box?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I have a Attendance table containing attendance of all the employee.
Currently i am working on report_generation page.
So, i want to pass emp_mail id through drop-down box to fetch records of that particular employee.
[here is the database table containing records](http://postimg.org/image/jerbl0e6j/)

Here is the code from the report generation page:

```
$dbh = getDBH(); 
$output = "";
$sql = "SELECT ATT.AttDate FROM attandance ATT"; 
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 
$results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
$arrDates = array(); 
foreach($results as $intKey=>$objAttDate)
{ 
     $arrDates[] = $objAttDate->AttDate; 
}
var_dump($arrDates);
```

Comment: Pls text, no pictures from code.

Comment: $dbh        = getDBH();
$output     = "";
$sql        = "SELECT ATT.AttDate FROM `attandance` ATT";
$query      = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results    = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$arrDates   = array();

foreach($results as $intKey=>$objAttDate){
    $arrDates[] = $objAttDate->AttDate;
}

var_dump($arrDates);

?>`